# Update Wheezy to Jessie on a dual boot (with win7)

Tags: debian, upgrade

I run a dual boot laptop with Debian Wheezy and Windows 7. I would like to upgrade Debian to Jessie. I am however a bit worried as grub - which let's me choose which OS to boot on startup - is replace by systemd. Anyone has experience with a similar update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two are very different programs:

- GRUB

`grub` is a bootloader, i.e. a program that starts the OSes. It will not be replace in the (this) upgrade of Debian.

- systemd

`systemd` is a system management tool. Its job is to manage and load all system services, daemons, or whichever startup programs you defined. It replaces the previous `init` suite and is loader AFTER the initial boot, i.e. completely separate from `grub` and does not affect it (except that the boot image of your Debian OS will be changed to start `systemd` over `init`)

If you did not have any special startup procedures defined in your `init` (e.g. to start a mail server, to start a daemon for a virtual LAN and so on) you should not have any trouble. If you did, you will have to migrate them. I personally did not run into any problem when I updated.

Debian also offers a [guide on how to test `systemd`](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd).

Comment: I must have misunderstood. But your answer makes things clear. Thnx.